# (Spring-Security) Expected a single expression attribute for

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

I got an error when I tried to use hasAnyRole on Spring-Security configuration.

My applicationContextSecurity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
<http  use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/"   access="ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR" />
    <intercept-url pattern='/paginas/' access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USUARIO', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR')"/> 

    <form-login login-page="/publico/login.xhtml"
        always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/paginas/agenda/index.xhtml"
        authentication-failure-url="/publico/login.jsf?login_error=1"/>
    <logout/>
    <remember-me />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="sincronizaDataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.login, p.permissao 
                                         FROM usuario u, usuario_permissao p 
                                        WHERE u.id = p.usuario 
                                          AND u.login = ?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT login, senha, ativo 
                                   FROM usuario 
                                  WHERE login = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Then I got this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a single expression attribute for [/paginas/]
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.processMap(ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:43)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.(ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:30)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
>       ... 31 more

Comment: Are you sure single quotes are acceptable inside the configuration? I don't think it's part of an xml tag. specifically: pattern='/paginas/' should probably be pattern="/paginas/"

Comment: I tried pattern="/paginas/**" and nothing happen :/